# sed - matching entire line after an ampersand

Tags: regex, sed

I'm having trouble getting sed to match (and replace) an entire line that contains ampersands. It seems to match right up until the first ampersand and then stop matching. And the replacement string replaces only that portion, and not the entire line.

```
sed -i 's/^error_reporting = .*/error_reporting = E_ALL \& \~E_DEPRECATED \& \~E_STRICT \& \~E_NOTICE/' /etc/php.ini
```

The replacement is correct, with the escaped ampersands. But the entire line is not replaced... only the part before the first existing ampersand. How can I specify to sed to match everything including ampersands?

**UPDATE**: I figured out the problem. I was calling the sed command from within a javascript script, and it was escaping the characters before passing it to the sed command. Double escaping the string fixed the issue.

Comment: Can't reproduce such behavior here. What OS and which version of sed are you using?

Comment: sed 4.5 on CentOS 8

Answer (score 1):

Also can't reproduce with GNU sed or default BSD sed on MacOS:

```
$ echo 'error_reporting = a & ~b & c' | gsed 's/^error_reporting = .*/error_reporting = E_ALL \& \~E_DEPRECATED \& \~E_STRICT \& \~E_NOTICE/'
error_reporting = E_ALL & ~E_DEPRECATED & ~E_STRICT & ~E_NOTICE
```